# PostgreSQL: How to make values obligatory in INSERT querys?

Tags: sql, postgresql, constraints

I'm trying to create a table with Postgresql, in which the value of `name` is required. That means, if i intend to make an `INSERT`, i'd be obligated to fill the value of `name`.

I'm trying to create like that:

```
CREATE TABLE person (
  id SERIAL,
  name VARCHAR(64),
  height REAL,
  PRIMARY KEY(id)
)
```

I don't know if there is a "REQUIRED" in SQL, but in my researchs i still didn't find it.

Comment: `id SERIAL NOT NULL`

Comment: Make name `NOT NULL`. It's good policy in general to be explicit on whether each column is `NULL` or `NOT NULL`, rather than leaving it up to defaults.

Comment: Thank you very much, it was exactly that.

Comment: If you need a customized validation rule you can combine a `NOT NULL` constraint with a `CHECK` constraint. For example if you need all the letters in upper case with a minimum of three characters you can do: `NOT NULL CHECK (length(name) >= 3 and name = upper(name))`.

Comment: Thank you so much, Mr. Impaler, appreciate it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Serg and Jeroen Mostert pointed in the comments, i only had to make it `NOT NULL`, so it went out like that:

```
CREATE TABLE person (
  id SERIAL NOT NULL,
  name VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
  height REAL NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY(id)
)
```

Comment: As a side note: [Don't use serial](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don't_Do_This#Don.27t_use_serial)

Comment: Hi Mr. horse, thanks for the side note. Could you tell me better why shoudn't i use SERIAL ?